# Turning on secondary screen moves all windows to that screen

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have a two monitor setup. Monitor 1 is my primary monitor and the desktop is extended onto the second monitor.
However whenever I turn on the second monitor, all of the windows from the primary window move across to the second monitor.
I'm on Windows 8 and don't have any special window management software or anything like that.
It's quite irritating since the second monitor is lower resolution and resizes all of my windows.
The first monitor is definitely marked as the primary monitor.
It seems to happen again after turning off both monitors and letting the computer go to sleep.

Anyway to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I began using a program at work called DisplayFusion to eliminate exactly this problem. I was also able to add a taskbar to the secondary monitor. The full version costs about $20 but the free version should fix the problem you describe above. Link below.

 
 http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Windows8/